# Java parse data from html table with jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I want to get the data from the table from the link.

link:

https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/aapl/financials?query=balance-sheet

I´ve tried my code but it doens´t work

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/aapl/financials?query=balance-sheet").get();
        Elements trs = doc.select("td_genTable");



        for (Element tr : trs) {
            Elements tds = tr.getElementsByTag("td");
            Element td = tds.first();
            System.out.println(td.text());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me?  To get it to work

I´m not getting an output of the table. Nothing happens.

Comment: why it does not work? what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After test your code I've got and `Read time out` problem. Looking on Google I found [this post](https://www.javacodeexamples.com/jsoup-sockettimeoutexception-read-timed-out-connect-timed-out-fix/775) where suggest to **add an user agent to fix it and it worked for me**. So, you can try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // add user agent
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/aapl/financials?query=balance-sheet")
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").get();
        Elements trs = doc.select("tr");
        for (Element tr : trs) {
            Elements tds = tr.select(".td_genTable");
            // avoid tr headers that produces NullPointerException
            if(tds.size() == 0) continue;
            // look for siblings (see the html structure of the web)
            Element td = tds.first().siblingElements().first();
            System.out.println(td.text());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**I have added User agent option and fix some query errors**. This will be useful to start your work ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me :)

Comment: But now it just prints out the firtst(left) column.

Comment: @Marek yes now the connection problem is fixed so you can analyze the html structure and set the proper queries on Jsoup to do your work. Try to do that, if you have problems you can create other new question with your attempt and I will help you.